# Using pandas.DataFrame to get format of excel cell?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**TLDR:** Uploading an existing excel file to a pandas DataFrame using `df = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx)`. Currently unable to find any way to get the format (in terms of the excel sheet, i.e. General, Number, Currency, etc.) from the DataFrame `df`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Associated Topics:** I know this is possible in PHP and C#, but I would prefer to stay in python for the simplicity.

You can [set a style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) really easily in pandas, but I can't find any documentation which shows how to get a style for a particular item in the DataFrame.

Comment: Pandas' main [dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes) includes a handful: `object`, `int64`, `float64`, `bool`, `datetime64`, `timedelta[ns]`, `category`. While new development is extending pandas, don't forget its prime objective is data analytics not serving as a reporting/user interface. Process what you need in pandas and export to Excel, XML, HTML, PDF, Latex, etc. for end-use dissemination needs with styling and formatting.